# VB.net - unable to delete sqlite file on form.load

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I am trying to delete on form.load (after I make a copy of it).  I get an error

"The process cannot access the file because its being used by another process.

If I create a button on the form and run the same code, it deletes the file.

```
 '\\\\\\\ Copy old data into new database

        connect.Open()


        Dim attatch As String = "ATTACH '" + bklocation + "' as bkbackup"
        Dim fillspecinfo As String = "Insert into bkbackup.specinfo Select * from specinfo"
        Dim fillballcompany As String = " Insert into bkbackup.BallCompany select * from BallCompany"
        Dim fillbowlingballs As String = "Insert into bkbackup.BowlingBalls select * from BowlingBalls"
        Dim fillcustomerinfo As String = "Insert into bkbackup.CustomerInfo select * from CustomerInfo"
        Dim fillcustomernotes As String = "Insert into bkbackup.CustomerNotes select * from CustomerNotes"
        Dim fillremthumbid As String = "Insert into bkbackup.RemThumbID select * from RemThumbID"

        Dim cmd28 As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(attatch, connect)
        Dim cmd29 As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(fillspecinfo, connect)
        Dim cmd30 As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(fillballcompany, connect)
        Dim cmd31 As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(fillbowlingballs, connect)
        Dim cmd32 As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(fillcustomerinfo, connect)
        Dim cmd33 As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(fillcustomernotes, connect)
        Dim cmd34 As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(fillremthumbid, connect)

        cmd28.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd29.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd30.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd31.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd32.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd33.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd34.ExecuteNonQuery()



    connect.Close()

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

If connect.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(dblocation)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
end If
```

Any help would be appreciated in this matter.  Thanks you

Comment: You didnt show the  copy part, so hard to guess what is wrong.  Those GC ops likely are not needed though

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I added the copying code.

Comment: **Always**  dispose of **anything and everything** which has a dispose method with a `using` block if possible. You also dont really need 7 unique DBCOmmand objects (nor 28 ?!) - just give it new text

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Just a system admin trying to code :)  I will look up USING and look into all the DBCommands objects I created.  Thanks again